# MacBook Air windows 8.1 keyboard and trackpad not working?

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard, windows-8.1, trackpad

i have a macbook air.
i use Windows 8.1 but keyboard and trackpad not working.
No problem with the Mac OSx
Please help me.

Comment: probably you need drivers for keyboard and trackpad

Comment: I 've installed the current driver

Comment: check device manager if drivers installed working even if the hardward exist there or not, its the first step to check if something not working

Comment: Unknown USB device in the device manager.

Comment: USB\DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR_FAILURE

Comment: first thing first, keyboard and trackpad are in device manager or not?

Comment: and you can just double click on unknown device, update driver, check online for drivers, if they exist windows will install it for you

Comment: yes, but Windows dont find a driver.

Comment: Very very problem now.

Comment: otherway around is check your modal spec find device detail n modal and google is you only option otherwise use external keybaord n mouse, you can also try a tool name `unknown device identifier` google it install it n take it from there